# Formal equivalent to "Sanity check"?

Tags: single-word-requests, formality

I am looking for a formal equivalent to the phrase "Sanity check".

The context of this is that I am writing my dissertation, and I have performed an experiment using one method that resulted in a result far from the expected. So, I then performed an alternative experiment as a "sanity check" to check my first method wasn't clearly wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you did a [**cross-check**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cross-check) or a [**verification**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/verification).